# House icon for home page

Tags: icons

What happened to the little house icon that took you directly to your home page on a MacBook?

Comment: Like in the browser? Or an icon in the Finder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the browser, but as I'm not entirely sure...:

**Browser**: Right-click Safari's toolbar/address bar, select *Customize Toolbar*, and drag the *Home* item to the toolbar.

---

**Finder**: Open a new Finder window, and, if necessary, navigate to your home folder. Drag the icon in the window title bar (it's called a *proxy icon*) to the Finder's sidebar.